# How to link multiple frames in java

Tags: java, mysql, frame

I created Login and Register frames separated which both connected to MySQL. If I just run the register frame, I can insert a new user to the database. However, If I run the login frame which includes the register frame inside and press register, the button that adds in the register frame does not work even the text fields are filled out.

```
//this is Login frame class

package YASAR;

import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.sql.*;
import java.awt.EventQueue;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.border.EmptyBorder;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.JComboBox;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;

public class GirisEkrani extends JFrame {
    static JButton btnKullancEkle = new JButton("Kullan\u0131c\u0131 Ekle");
    public static JPanel contentPane;
    private static JTextField textField;
    private static JComboBox comboBox = new JComboBox();
    private static JButton btnBalan = new JButton("Ba\u011Flan");
    private static  JLabel lblParola = new JLabel("Parola :");
    private static JLabel lblXaampeBalanlamad = new JLabel("Xaampe Ba\u011Flan\u0131lamad\u0131");
    //private static KullaniciEkle ke=new KullaniciEkle();
    /**
     * Launch the application.
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                lblXaampeBalanlamad.setVisible(false);
                try {

                    GirisEkrani frame = new GirisEkrani();
                    frame.setVisible(true);

                    try {
        Connection con=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/yasar","ozkan","******");

        btnKullancEkle.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                frame.setVisible(false);
                KullaniciEkle ke=new KullaniciEkle();
                ke.setVisible(true);



            }
        });


        btnBalan.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                frame.setVisible(false);

                deneme abc=new deneme();
                abc.setVisible(true);

            }
        });


        con.close();
                    }

        catch(SQLException e) {


            textField.setEditable(false);
            btnKullancEkle.setEnabled(false);
            comboBox.setEnabled(false);
            btnBalan.setEnabled(false);
            lblParola.setVisible(false);
            lblXaampeBalanlamad.setVisible(true);


            e.printStackTrace();
        }

                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });

    }

    /**
     * Create the frame.
     */
    public GirisEkrani() {
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setBounds(100, 100, 286, 300);
        contentPane = new JPanel();
        contentPane.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5));
        setContentPane(contentPane);
        contentPane.setLayout(null);

        textField = new JTextField();
        textField.setBounds(74, 129, 124, 19);
        contentPane.add(textField);
        textField.setColumns(10);


        comboBox.setBounds(74, 42, 124, 21);
        contentPane.add(comboBox);


        btnBalan.setBounds(74, 184, 124, 33);
        contentPane.add(btnBalan);

        btnKullancEkle.setBounds(74, 227, 124, 26);
        contentPane.add(btnKullancEkle);


        lblParola.setBounds(10, 132, 45, 13);
        contentPane.add(lblParola);
        lblXaampeBalanlamad.setBounds(74, 90, 162, 29);

        contentPane.add(lblXaampeBalanlamad);
    }

}
```

```
// And this is register frame class where I add user 

package YASAR;

import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.EventQueue;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.border.EmptyBorder;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

import java.sql.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.Font;

public class KullaniciEkle extends JFrame {

    public static JPanel contentPane;
    public static JTextField textField;
    public static JTextField textField_1;
    public static JTextField textField_2;
    public static JLabel lblIsim;
    public static JLabel lblSoyisim;
    public static JButton btnNewButton = new JButton("Ekle");

    /**
     * Launch the application.
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    KullaniciEkle frame = new KullaniciEkle();
                    frame.setVisible(true);



                    try {
    Connection con=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/yasar","ozkan","******");

    btnNewButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

        String input="INSERT INTO kullanicilar (TC,name,surname) VALUES(?,?,?)";
            try {


                PreparedStatement ps=con.prepareStatement(input);

                ps.setInt(1, Integer.parseInt(textField.getText()));
                ps.setString(2, textField_1.getText());
                ps.setString(3, textField_2.getText());


                //ps.execute();
                if(ps.executeUpdate()>0) {
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "user added","user add",JOptionPane.OK_CANCEL_OPTION);
                }


            }catch(SQLException f) {
                f.printStackTrace();
            }

            finally {System.out.println("pressed");}

                frame.setVisible(false);
                new GirisEkrani().setVisible(true);

                }
    });

                    }
                        catch(SQLException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }


                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    /**
     * Create the frame.
     */
    public KullaniciEkle() {
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setBounds(100, 100, 285, 300);
        contentPane = new JPanel();
        contentPane.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5));
        setContentPane(contentPane);
        contentPane.setLayout(null);

        textField = new JTextField();
        textField.setBounds(87, 67, 96, 19);
        contentPane.add(textField);
        textField.setColumns(10);

        textField_1 = new JTextField();
        textField_1.setBounds(87, 112, 96, 19);
        contentPane.add(textField_1);
        textField_1.setColumns(10);

        textField_2 = new JTextField();
        textField_2.setBounds(87, 160, 96, 19);
        contentPane.add(textField_2);
        textField_2.setColumns(10);
        btnNewButton.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.PLAIN, 10));



        btnNewButton.setBounds(93, 232, 85, 21);
        contentPane.add(btnNewButton);

        JLabel lblTc = new JLabel("TC");
        lblTc.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.PLAIN, 10));
        lblTc.setBounds(10, 70, 45, 13);
        contentPane.add(lblTc);

        lblIsim = new JLabel("\u0130sim");
        lblIsim.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.PLAIN, 10));
        lblIsim.setBounds(10, 115, 45, 13);
        contentPane.add(lblIsim);

        lblSoyisim = new JLabel("Soyisim");
        lblSoyisim.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.PLAIN, 10));
        lblSoyisim.setBounds(10, 163, 45, 13);
        contentPane.add(lblSoyisim);
    }

}
```

Comment: Post the code. So we can help you. Do you get any errors?

Comment: I don't get any errors.

Comment: I checked your code and it' working fine. I don't get any errors when opening the register window from the login window. Maybe you should look at the database connection.

Comment: I can open either but the main problem is that I cannot insert a new user from the login window. I can insert if I run the register class only.

Comment: Put your button action listener inside the constructor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to put this code inside your `Constructor`.

```
btnNewButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

        String input="INSERT INTO kullanicilar (TC,name,surname) VALUES(?,?,?)";
            try {


                PreparedStatement ps=con.prepareStatement(input);

                ps.setInt(1, Integer.parseInt(textField.getText()));
                ps.setString(2, textField_1.getText());
                ps.setString(3, textField_2.getText());


                //ps.execute();
                if(ps.executeUpdate()>0) {
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "user added","user add",JOptionPane.OK_CANCEL_OPTION);
                }


            }catch(SQLException f) {
                f.printStackTrace();
            }

            finally {System.out.println("pressed");}

                frame.setVisible(false);
                new GirisEkrani().setVisible(true);

                }
    });
```

Finally, it will look like this,

```
import java.awt.EventQueue;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.border.EmptyBorder;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

import java.sql.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.Font;

public class KullaniciEkle extends JFrame {

    public static JPanel contentPane;
    public static JTextField textField;
    public static JTextField textField_1;
    public static JTextField textField_2;
    public static JLabel lblIsim;
    public static JLabel lblSoyisim;
    public static JButton btnNewButton = new JButton("Ekle");

    /**
     * Launch the application.
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    KullaniciEkle frame = new KullaniciEkle();
                    frame.setVisible(true);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    /**
     * Create the frame.
     */
    public KullaniciEkle() {
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setBounds(100, 100, 285, 300);
        contentPane = new JPanel();
        contentPane.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5));
        setContentPane(contentPane);
        contentPane.setLayout(null);

        textField = new JTextField();
        textField.setBounds(87, 67, 96, 19);
        contentPane.add(textField);
        textField.setColumns(10);

        textField_1 = new JTextField();
        textField_1.setBounds(87, 112, 96, 19);
        contentPane.add(textField_1);
        textField_1.setColumns(10);

        textField_2 = new JTextField();
        textField_2.setBounds(87, 160, 96, 19);
        contentPane.add(textField_2);
        textField_2.setColumns(10);
        btnNewButton.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.PLAIN, 10));

        btnNewButton.setBounds(93, 232, 85, 21);
        contentPane.add(btnNewButton);

        JLabel lblTc = new JLabel("TC");
        lblTc.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.PLAIN, 10));
        lblTc.setBounds(10, 70, 45, 13);
        contentPane.add(lblTc);

        lblIsim = new JLabel("\u0130sim");
        lblIsim.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.PLAIN, 10));
        lblIsim.setBounds(10, 115, 45, 13);
        contentPane.add(lblIsim);

        lblSoyisim = new JLabel("Soyisim");
        lblSoyisim.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.PLAIN, 10));
        lblSoyisim.setBounds(10, 163, 45, 13);
        contentPane.add(lblSoyisim);

        btnNewButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                btnNewButtonActionPerformed(e);
            }
        });

    }

    private void btnNewButtonActionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
        try {
            Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/yasar", "ozkan", "******");

            String input = "INSERT INTO kullanicilar (TC,name,surname) VALUES(?,?,?)";
            try {

                PreparedStatement ps = con.prepareStatement(input);

                ps.setInt(1, Integer.parseInt(textField.getText()));
                ps.setString(2, textField_1.getText());
                ps.setString(3, textField_2.getText());

                //ps.execute();
                if (ps.executeUpdate() > 0) {
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "user added", "user add", JOptionPane.OK_CANCEL_OPTION);
                }

            } catch (SQLException f) {
                f.printStackTrace();
            } finally {
                System.out.println("pressed");
            }

            //Instead of frame use this keyword
            this.setVisible(false);
            new GirisEkrani().setVisible(true);

        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

**NOTE:-** This is not the best practice to communicate with the database.

Comment: It worked, I really appreciate it, thanks!

Comment: Pleased to know it helped :)